# C# XNA Collision Detection with list of objects

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I am currently learning C# and XNA and I am having some troubles with getting my collision detection to work properly. I wish for my player to disappear when the Enemy object intersects.

**Below shows my code within the Obj class**

```
class Obj
{
    public Vector2 position;
    public float rotation = 0.0f;
    public Texture2D spriteIndex;
    public string spriteName;
    public float speed = 0.0f;
    public float scale = 1.0f;
    public bool alive = true;
    public Rectangle area;
    public bool solid = false;


    public Obj(Vector2 pos)
    {
        position = pos;
    }

    private Obj()
    {

    }

    public virtual void Update()
    {
        if (!alive) return;

        UpdateArea();
        pushTo(speed, rotation);
    }

    public virtual void LoadContent(ContentManager content)
    {
        spriteIndex = content.Load<Texture2D>("sprites\\" + spriteName);
        area = new Rectangle(0, 0, spriteIndex.Width, spriteIndex.Height);
    }

    public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        if (!alive) return;

        Rectangle Size;
        Vector2 center = new Vector2(spriteIndex.Width / 2, spriteIndex.Height / 2);

        spriteBatch.Draw(spriteIndex, position, null, Color.White, MathHelper.ToRadians(rotation), center, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

    }

    public bool Collision(Vector2 pos, Obj obj)
    {
        Rectangle newArea = new Rectangle(area.X, area.Y, area.Width, area.Height);
        newArea.X += (int)pos.X;
        newArea.Y += (int)pos.Y;

        foreach (Obj o in Items.objList)
        {
            if (o.GetType() == obj.GetType() && o.solid)
                if (o.area.Intersects(newArea))
                    return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Obj Collision(Obj obj)
    {
        foreach (Obj o in Items.objList)
        {
            if (o.GetType() == obj.GetType())
                if (o.area.Intersects(area))
                    return o;
        }
        return new Obj();
    }

    public void UpdateArea()
    {
        area.X = (int)position.X - (spriteIndex.Width / 2);
        area.Y = (int)position.Y - (spriteIndex.Height / 2);
    }

    public T CheckCollisionAgainst<T>() where T : Obj
    {
        // If collision detected, returns the colliding object; otherwise null.
        return Items.objList
            .OfType<T>()
            .FirstOrDefault(o => o.solid && o.area.Intersects(area));
    }

    public virtual void pushTo(float pix, float dir)
    {
        float newX = (float)Math.Cos(MathHelper.ToRadians(dir));
        float newY = (float)Math.Sin(MathHelper.ToRadians(dir));
        position.X += pix * (float)newX;
        position.Y += pix * (float)newY;
    }
}
```

I am cycling through each Item in my objList to see if they intersect with each other, in this case, I want my Player to disappear if the Enemy intersects with them but this is not happening.

**This code is from my Player class**

```
class Player : Obj
{
    KeyboardState keyboard;
    KeyboardState prevKeyboard;

    float spd;

    public static Player player;

    public Player(Vector2 pos) 
        : base(pos)
    {
        position = pos;
        spd = 4;
        spriteName = "WhiteBall";
        solid = false;
        player = this;
    }

    public override void Update()
    {
        player = this;
        //If the player is NOT alive, end.
        if (!alive) return;

        keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();

        //Keyboard controls for game
        if(keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.W) && !Collision(new Vector2(0, -spd), new Enemy(new Vector2(0, 0))))
        {
            position.Y -= spd;
        }
        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.A) && !Collision(new Vector2(-spd, 0), new Enemy(new Vector2(0, 0))))
        {
            position.X -= spd;
        }

        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.S) && !Collision(new Vector2(0, spd), new Enemy(new Vector2(0, 0))))
        {
            position.Y += spd;
        }

        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.D) && !Collision(new Vector2(spd, 0), new Enemy(new Vector2(0, 0))))
        {
            position.X += spd;
        }
        prevKeyboard = keyboard;

        //Collision with enemy
        Enemy enemy = CheckCollisionAgainst<Enemy>();
        if (enemy != null)
        {
            alive = false;
        }

        base.Update();
    }


    public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.DrawString(Game1.font, "Pick Up The Crew", new      Vector2(350, 0), Color.White);

        base.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
}
```

If it intersects with the Enemy, it should disappear but this doesnt seem to be happening.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the condition. Your function returns o if and only if o and obj are of the same type

Comment: What is Obj.area - rectangle I presume? Also what is the area of the enemy you assign - `new Enemy(new Vector2(0, 0))`?

Comment: @Discosultan Obj.area is indeed a rectangle and the size of Enemy is calculated from: public void `UpdateArea()
        {
            area.X = (int)position.X - (spriteIndex.Width / 2);
            area.Y = (int)position.Y - (spriteIndex.Height / 2);
        }`

Comment: But at the time of collision detection `Obj o = Collision(new Enemy(new Vector2(0, 0)));`, isn't the area of the enemy 0 because `UpdateArea` has not been called yet?

Comment: @Discosultan have the `public Obj Collision(Obj obj)` method first and then after that I call the `public void UpdateArea()` method. What should I do then?

Comment: Is `Items.objList` a list of all the objects in your game world?

Comment: @Discosultan it is, i use `obj.List.Add(new Enemy(new Vector2(500, 500)));` to add my enemy but he is constantly changing positions when the game runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments you provided, I'm taking a shot here and providing a possible solution (ensure `UpdateArea` is called before calling this):

```
public T CheckCollisionAgainst<T>() where T : Obj
{      
    // If collision detected, returns the colliding object; otherwise null.
    return Items.objList
        .OfType<T>()
        .FirstOrDefault(o => o.area.Intersects(area));
}
```

---

```
Enemy enemy = CheckCollisionAgainst<Enemy>();
if (enemy != null)
{
    alive = false;
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I have placed the CheckCollision code after the UpdateArea method in the Obj class, where do I need to place the second block?

Comment: Whereever you test for collision. I think you did the test in the Player class in your original post. Replace this: `//Collision with enemy
Obj o = Collision(new Enemy(new Vector2(0, 0)));
if (o.GetType() == typeof(Enemy))
{
    alive = false;
}`

Comment: I have received an error with `if (enemy != null)` saying does not exist in the current context.

Comment: My bad, I updated the answer. Simply change `Enemy o =` to `Enemy enemy =`.

Comment: Ah thanks, I have tried what you suggested but it doesn't seem to be working for me. The enemy moves towards the player but once they collide with the player, the player is not removed.

Comment: I'm afraid I need more information to be able to help. Could you include the code for player death `if (!alive) { ... }`? And also you set area.X and area.Y in `UpdateArea()`, but where do you set the **Width** and **Height** of the area?

Comment: I have edited my original post to include all code from the player and obj classes, hope that helps

Comment: When you create a new Enemy, do you set `enemy.solid = true` anywhere? It might be that they are simply not marked as collidable. For testing purposes, you can also change `.FirstOrDefault(o => o.solid && o.area.Intersects(area))` to `.FirstOrDefault(o => o.area.Intersects(area))`

Comment: I don't, as you can see at the top of the Player class, I have solid = false; does this need to be true and do I also have to set solid = true; on the enemy class?

Comment: Depends on your intent. When I first looked at the code, I thought that solid determines whether the object should be included in collision detection or not. So you can either set solid to **true** or remove the check for solid in `CheckCollisionAgainst` method as I brought out in prev comment.

Comment: My intent was to use solid to determine whether the object could be removed by another object. For example, the enemy removes the player and the player collecting a collectible etc.

Comment: I see. It probably won't work so well with the `CheckCollisionAgainst` I had written before. I updated my answer for `CheckCollisionAgainst` method. Could you check if Player is now properly removed?

Comment: `o.area` doesn't exist in the current context. Also, whenever I use your code, I am removing the `class` from T : class, Obj as it cannot specify both a constraint class and the class or struct

Comment: That's fine. Sorry for the typos in the code. I don't have the possibility at the moment to actually try this out. Anyway, I updated my answer once again. It should now compile.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help that you are giving me. For some reason, the ball now doesn't show up on the screen. I don't mind waiting for you to be able to try this out yourself.

Comment: That indicates that the collision detection works and player.alive is set to false. It sounds to me as if collision detection is actually run before the proper areas are set for Player/Enemies. Try changing to the following line in LoadContent: `area = new Rectangle((int)position.X - (spriteIndex.Width / 2), (int)position.Y - (spriteIndex.Height / 2), spriteIndex.Width, spriteIndex.Height);`. You should ensure that LoadContent is called for Enemy **before** it is added to `Items.objList`.

Comment: That has worked! My player is removed when they hit the enemy. Thanks a lot for the help, I know it was a long winded process but I am thankful